# allocation of amount to different fields javascript

Tags: javascript, field, allocation

I have a problem, in fact at least I do not know how. I have several fields revealing different amount  each position is identified by an id example: p1, p2, p3 etc. ...

So this fields contain amounts, in their decimal form.

what I wish to make. Because in fact I will be led to allocate an amount entered in a field that is a deposit.

that is to say as long as the amount of deposit is> 0 then I spread over the various post

For example let's say I have

```
 300 = p1, p2 and p3 = 120 = 50
and I have a deposit for an amount of 450 Euros, so I would
p1 = 0 and o1 fields (fields that is revealing what has been imputed) 300
p2 = 0 and the fields 120 o2
p3 = 20 fields and o3 = 30
```

I actually tried by a number of conditions but I tangled brushes.

this is what it gave:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ventilation()
 {
 var montantacompte = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;
 var p1             = document.getElementById("p1").value;
 var p2             = document.getElementById("p2").value;  
 var p3             = document.getElementById("p3").value;  
 var p4             = document.getElementById("p4").value;   
 var p5             = document.getElementById("p5").value;      
 var p7             = document.getElementById("p7").value;                  
 var p8             = document.getElementById("p8").value;   
 var p9             = document.getElementById("p9").value;   
 var p10            = document.getElementById("p10").value; 
 var p11            = document.getElementById("p11").value;   
 var p12            = document.getElementById("p12").value;  
 var p13            = document.getElementById("p13").value;


    if(p1>0 &&p1-montantacompte>=0)
     {

         f1=p1-montantacompte;
         document.getElementById('p1').value=f1;
         document.getElementById('o1').value=Math.round(montantacompte*100)/100;
     }
        if(p1>0 &&p1-montantacompte<=(p1+p2))
     {
         reste1=montantacompte-p1;
         impute=p1;
         impute2=reste1;
         f1=m1-impute;
         document.getElementById('p1').value=f1;
         document.getElementById('o1').value=Math.round(impute*100)/100;
         document.getElementById('o2').value=Math.round(impute2*100)/100;

     }

 }
</script>
```

I also tried with a loop but well I also tangled brush, my small knowledge of javascript does not help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ventilation()
 {
 var reste          = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;
 var ac             = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;
 var p1             = document.getElementById("p1").value;
 var p2             = document.getElementById("p2").value;  
 var p3             = document.getElementById("p3").value;  
 var p4             = document.getElementById("p4").value;   
 var p5             = document.getElementById("p5").value;      
 var p7             = document.getElementById("p7").value;                  
 var p8             = document.getElementById("p8").value;   
 var p9             = document.getElementById("p9").value;   
 var p10            = document.getElementById("p10").value; 
 var p11            = document.getElementById("p11").value;   
 var p12            = document.getElementById("p12").value;  
 var p13            = document.getElementById("p13").value;
 var c              = 1;
 while(reste>0 && c<13)
 {
     if(reste> 'p'+c)
     {
         reste = 'p'+c -  ac;
         document.getElementById('p'+c).value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
         print reste;
     }
 }

</script>
```

suddenly, I do not know because every time I do not arrived more advancing in both cases.

in advance thank you to all and anyone who can help me progress.

Sincerely yours.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Are you not receiving the correct values or your logic is not moving the values around to the correct fields?

Comment: In fact, as you can see on this picture I have differents fields with many amounts, http://www.developpez.net/forums/attachments/p99396d1342770574/webmasters-developpement-web/javascript/repartition-test-condition/titrez.png I have an oder input when someone do a payment for exemple if someone do a payment of 25000 it must allocate the 25000 between all the fileds, until the amount given in the input is equal to 0.

for exemple if I have p1=300 and p2 = 150 and p3 = 75 and I have a payment of 465 Euros the repartition will be 300 for p1 150 for p2 and 15 for p3 and amount left on p3 will be 60

Comment: So your logic is not allocating these values correctly. Your variable names are a bit hard to follow. What is `honoraires`? where is it defined?

Comment: honoraires is a mistake in fact. it wont be used there

In fact I have an input in which I write the payment, and I would like to allocate the payment beetween all this Post I'll do an other exemple .

In the table on the right is written the original amount left to be payed On the right is written the amount that will be imputed there.

for exemple If we have at the beginning

I= Imputed     L =Left to be payed
I=0  / L  150
I=0 /  L  50
I=0 /  L  25
And that I have a payment of 220

It will be


I=150 / L= 0
I=50 / L=  0
I=20 / L= 5

Comment: here is an other picture to explain http://www.developpez.net/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=99438&stc=1&d=1342792771

Comment: That site requires an account to view the images. Can you explain the conditions that determine how the input amount is allocated to the different fields?

Comment: by order.in fact the amount is allocated to p1 then to p2 etc...

Comment: What determines the amount though? do these orders have a number associated with them that you apply to the input?

Comment: in fact, you have p1, p2, p3 to p14... And until p1 is not equal to 0 you allowate a part of the payment, for example if the payment is < p1 you will allowate all, and the left payment will be p1 - the payment. If it is more it will allocate all to p1 then to p2 etc... I do not know if my english is verry correct in order for you to understand what i'm trying to expalin.

Comment: Its tough to visualize. could you make a table in your question as an example? i think i'm understanding but if i could see. that would be better

Comment: Could set up a JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Okay i've got it now. so your JS isn't working. give me a min i'll put something together

Comment: thanks a lot. I know how to do it in php but I really need it to be displayed in the screen before validating the data

Comment: If that answers your question, please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this issue, the user inputs a Payment Amount then this amount is applied to line items on an order.

Input: 17100

Item 1:  `<input id="p1" class="items" value="16000.00 €"/>`

Item 2:  `<input id="p1" class="items" value="535.00 €"/>`

Item 3:  `<input id="p1" class="items" value="955.00 €"/>`

```
 function getItems()
 {
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");

 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
     items[i] = document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value;
 }

 return items;
 }

 function setItems(items,payAmt)
 {
   document.getElementById("inputField").value = payAmt;
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
   {
      document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value = items[i];
   }
 }

 function itemSum(items)
 {
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    sum = items[i] + sum;
}

return sum;
 }

 function payment(inputElm)
 {
 var items = getItems();
 var payAmt = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
 var i = 0;
 var sum = itemSum(items);

 while(payAmt != 0 && sum != 0)
 {
     var temp = items[i] - payAmt;
     if(temp > 0)
     {
         items[i] = temp;
         break;
     }
     else if(temp < 0)
     {
         items[i] = 0;
         payAmt = temp*-1;
      }
     i++;
     sum = itemSum(items);
 }

  setItems(items, payAmt);
 }
```

I think that should do it if I understand your problem correctly. You'll need to make sure the IDs match up and this is untested so there'll be a bug or two in there more than likely.

Comment: it says to me 
         items[i] = document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value;
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: see update to `getItems` function and added class to all the order item input elements. That should take care of it.

Comment: Come on bro i practically wrote this for you. Throw me an answer check.

Comment: thanks for the help, it says to meUncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined index.php:506
payment index.php:506
onblur

Comment: I've change here {
         var temp = items[i] - payAmt;
         if(temp > 0)
         {
             items[i] = temp;
             break;
         }
         else if(temp < 0)
         {
             items[i] = 0;
             payAmt = temp*-1;
          }
         i++;

It works almost...

Comment: In fact the problem i have is when the amount put in the field is > than the sum of all p...

For example if p1+p2+p3= 500 and that in the input field I put 550 the script is blocked and the page freezed...

Comment: I just fixed it. I had some syntax issues and the while loop in payment could never end in some scenarios but I fix it. Should work.

Comment: Oops, I accidently copied `setItem` twice. Try it now.

Comment: thanks it works perfect fully why does it change the amount of the input field?

Comment: Oh I have it updating the input field based on the amount left over after the payments. If you don't want that, go to the setItems function and delete/comment out the first line.

Comment: Select the check if this answers you question.